# Resetting IDENTITY column after deleting one or two is a good practice in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have table with 100 records in SQL Server Database I deleted 50th record in the table.

is it a good idea to reset identity column for maintaining the sequnce of items?
what is benefit we get by resetiing the order?

Comment: For what reason would you want a sequence without gaps? After all, an identity column should just identify each row by a unique value. I would never mess with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official Microsoft statement is that you should expect gaps when using `IDENTITY`, so I would infer its absolutely fine if your deletions cause the gap. There is no reason to fill in the gap

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/739013/failover-or-restart-results-in-reseed-of-identity

Since that is a very long thread on a tangentially related topic, relevant quote below:

> As documented in books online for previous versions of SQL Server the
>   identity property does not guarantee the absence of gaps, this
>   statement remains true for the above workarounds. These solutions do
>   help with removing the gaps that occur as part of restarting the
>   instance in SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 0):

It is not always a good idea to reset your identity columns, think about other tables who might refer to the table using foreign keys. You would have to re-index those foreign keys as well, which could lead to corrupt or incorrect relationships.

If you are sure other tables do not rely on your identity column, then you can safely reset the column. the benefits of an ordered table does not outweigh the risks in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

NO!, this is - in general! - not a good practice!

The `IDENTITY` (and other `SEQUENCE`-based approaches) **are not meant to create contigous line** of IDs.

If one is missing - it is missing. If many are missing - just the same. That's it.

If you need a gap-less number, you must create own logic to assure this.